# Using Robocopy to copy files based on a word in the file name

Tags: archiving, robocopy

So ok, I'm looking for a solution to scan a hard drive.

And look for folders in that hard drive that have #ARCHIVE#, and move said folders to a \nas\archive\

I know you can use Robocopy to copy files based on last modify date but that's not really want i'm looking for.

Any solutions?

Thank you

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: While not addressing the question, is the purpose of this to backup files _(asking because of the archiving tag)_?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retain folder structure, and move subdirectory content (including empty subdirectories), then here's some PowerShell to get you started...

```
$SourceDir = (Get-Location).Path
$Folders = Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceDir -Filter '*#ARCHIVE#*' -Recurse -Directory 
foreach ($Folder in $Folders) {
    robocopy.exe "$($Folder.FullName)" "D:\nas\archive$(($Folder.FullName).Replace($SourceDir,''))" /MOVE /E
}
```

This assumes you'll be running these PowerShell commands from your source directory location, and drive D: contains your target \nas\archive folder.  Adjust as necessary.